# Error getting Membership data in LINQ expression returning multiple items

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a page that displays a list of employees.

All the employee authentication data is stored in the .NET membership tables, with other data like Name stored in a related table named Employees.

Here's my code that is getting the list of employees:

```
var viewModel = employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).
                            Select(e => new EmployeeViewModel
                            {
                                EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID,
                                Name = e.Name,
                                Email = Membership.GetUser(e.UserID).Email,
                                Active = e.Active
                            });
```

I get this error:

> **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser GetUser(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

I did some research, and found that I need to pull the `Membership.GetUser` function outside of the LINQ expression. This would work great if I was only getting a single employee, but I'm returning a list, so the user would be different on each iteration.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate your select on the "client" side with inserting a `ToArray()` before the `Select(..)`:

```
var viewModel = employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name)
                           .ToArray()
                           .Select(e => new EmployeeViewModel
                            {
                                EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID,
                                Name = e.Name,
                                Email = Membership.GetUser(e.UserID).Email,
                                Active = e.Active
                            });
```

In this case EF don't try to translate `Membership.GetUser` method.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, this solution although solves your problem, but introduces another one: it will execute N+1 selects where N is the count of employees.

To avoid that you can map your `MemberShip` tables in your EF model and you can create an relation between the `MemberShip` and your `Employee` table. Then you can get all the data with one select and without using `Membership.GetUser()`.

Comment: Or, if the Employees table is in the same Database as the aspnet_Membership table, you COULD create a linkage between them, allowing you to use something like e.Membership.Email  (You'd have to create a UserID field in your Employee table and load the appropriate GUIDs into it, then add the Membership table to your .edmx file)

Comment: If there are N employees, the suggested Linq would cause N+1 database queries wouldn't it? That will not scale to large numbers of employees, surely? The suggestion from @Dave of creating a link at the DB (and therefore model) level would allow a single SQL query.

Comment: Both of you are right. I focused on the quick fix and missed the select N+1. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Since this is for a web page displaying a list of employees, I suspect you'd start paging your list before the number of DB queries became an issue.

Comment: Even for a page size of 10 employees it is 10 times as many queries as you need though.